# create graphs from a file using boost library

Tags: c++, boost, graph, io

I'm trying to write a program who can read and create graphs from a file using BOOST library.
first, I start with some explications.
the file will be something like: http://pastebin.com/g4cgaHJB
every time I find a line like (t # 1) its mean graph with id 1.
(v 0 12) its mean vertex with id 0 and label 12.
(e 1 3 52) its mean edge with label 52 between vertex with id 1 and vertex with id 3.

I started with reading the file and every time I find(t # ..) I create a graph and I put it in a vector of graphs.
here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <ctime>
#include <set>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <unordered_set>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <boost/algorithm/string/split.hpp>
#include <boost/algorithm/string/classification.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
using namespace std;
using namespace boost;
using namespace boost::algorithm;



/*********************************************/
//vertex
struct VertexProperties
{
    int id;
    int label;

    VertexProperties(){}
    VertexProperties(unsigned i, unsigned l) : id(i), label(l) {}
};

//edge
struct EdgeProperties
{
    unsigned id;
    unsigned label;
    EdgeProperties(){}
    EdgeProperties(unsigned i, unsigned l) : id(i), label(l) {}
};

//Graph
struct GraphProperties
{
    unsigned id;
    unsigned label;
    GraphProperties()  {}
    GraphProperties(unsigned i, unsigned l) : id(i), label(l) {}
};


//adjency list
typedef boost::adjacency_list<
    boost::vecS, boost::vecS, boost::directedS,
    VertexProperties,
    EdgeProperties,
    GraphProperties
> Graph;


//descriptors
typedef boost::graph_traits<Graph>::vertex_descriptor vertex_t;
typedef std::pair<boost::graph_traits<Graph>::edge_descriptor, bool> edge_t;
//iterators
typedef graph_traits<Graph>::vertex_iterator vertex_iter;
typedef graph_traits<Graph>::edge_iterator edge_iter;
/****************************************************************************/
//le seuil int seuil;
std::vector<std::string> tokens;

/*
    programme principal
*/
int main()
{


    vector<Graph> dataG;  // vector<graphes> * pointsdataG;

    ifstream * file_reader= new ifstream("5.txt" ); //flux d'entrée pour opérer sur les fichiers.

    while (!file_reader->eof())
    {
        string line;

        file_reader->sync(); //Synchronise le tampon d'entree avec la source de donnees associee.

        getline(*file_reader, line); //lire les caracteres a partir du flux d'entree (file_reader) et les place dans une chaine: (line)
        if(line[0]=='t')  // ligne de transaction(graphe)
        {

            split(tokens, line, is_any_of(" "));
            int gid=atoi(tokens[2].c_str());
            Graph g(GraphProperties(gid,gid));


            cout<<gid<<endl;
            dataG.push_back(g);
        }
}
        std::cout << "dataG contains:";
        for (std::vector<Graph>::iterator it = dataG.begin() ; it != dataG.end(); ++it)
        {
            std::cout << ' ' << (*it)->label;
            std::cout << '\n';
        }
}
```

but I have a problem with this line

```
std::cout << ' ' << (*it)->id;
```

After solving this I will put the code every time I go forward :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, your `myvector` isn't defined or declared anywhere.

Secondly, the line you say you have a problem with `std::cout << ' ' << (*it)->id;`, doesn't exist in your code.

However, the problem is most likely the same as what you actually *do* have in your code. You are looping over a vector containing `adjacency_list` items, and then trying to extract a node value from the graph object.

You need an additional inner loop, to extract values from the nodes.

---

**update1**
This could be something like:

```
  std::cout << "dataG contains:";
  for (auto gr : dataG)
  {
    for (size_t i = 0 ; i < num_vertices(gr) ; ++i) {
      std::cout << ' ' << gr[i].id << std::endl;
    }
  }
```

---

**update2**

Your comments have confused me. If what you wanted to do was to populate the adjacency_list, then this is how you could do it:

```
  while (!file_reader->eof())
  {
    string line;

    file_reader->sync();

    getline(*file_reader, line);
    std::stringstream ss(line);
    char lineType;
    ss >> lineType;
    if(lineType =='t')
    {
      char dummy;
      int gid;
      ss >> dummy >> gid;
      Graph g(GraphProperties(gid,gid));
      dataG.push_back(g);
    }  else if (lineType == 'v') {
      assert(!dataG.empty());
      int vId, vLabel;
      ss >> vId >> vLabel;
      boost::add_vertex(VertexProperties(vId, vLabel), dataG[dataG.size()-1]);
    } else if (lineType == 'e') {
      assert(!dataG.empty());
      int fromId, toId, vLabel;
      ss >> fromId >> toId >> vLabel;

      // Note that the EdgeProperty.id doesn't make sense with your input data
      // as it only contains [vertexFrom vertexTo edgeData]
      boost::add_edge(fromId, toId,
                      EdgeProperties(0, vLabel), dataG[dataG.size()-1]);
    }
  }
```

I believe your use of 'id' is redundant for vertices, as they will all have implicit id's attached to them. However, if you still want to have that as a vertex property, that is fine. However, you do the same for edges, but the edge entry data doesn't have an 'id' field.

---

**update3***

To access and output the contents of the graphs:

```
  typedef std::pair<edge_iter, edge_iter> edge_pair;
  std::cout << "dataG contains:" << std::endl;
  int c = 0;
  for (auto gr : dataG)
  {
    ++c;
    std::cout << "Graph " << c << " contains " << num_vertices(gr) << " vertices, and " << num_edges(gr) << " edges" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "  Vertex list: " << std::endl;
    for (size_t i = 0 ; i < num_vertices(gr) ; ++i) {
      std::cout << "    [" << i << "]   ID: " << gr[i].id << ", Label: " << gr[i].label << std::endl;
    }

    std::cout << "  Edge list: " << std::endl;
    edge_pair ep;
    for (ep = edges(gr); ep.first != ep.second; ++ep.first) {
      vertex_t from = source(*ep.first, gr);
      vertex_t to = target(*ep.first, gr);
      edge_t edg = edge(from, to, gr);
      std::cout << "    [" << gr[from].id << "," << gr[to].id << "]   ID: N/A,  Label: " <<  gr[edg.first].label << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
  }
```

**Output using '5.txt':**

```
dataG contains:
Graph 1 contains 3 vertices, and 3 edges
  Vertex list: 
    [0]   ID: 0, Label: 0
    [1]   ID: 1, Label: 3
    [2]   ID: 2, Label: 9
  Edge list: 
    [0,1]   ID: N/A,  Label: 10
    [0,2]   ID: N/A,  Label: 4
    [2,1]   ID: N/A,  Label: 68

Graph 2 contains 6 vertices, and 3 edges
  Vertex list: 
    [0]   ID: 0, Label: 2
    [1]   ID: 1, Label: 11
    [2]   ID: 2, Label: 6
    [3]   ID: 3, Label: 10
    [4]   ID: 4, Label: 18
    [5]   ID: 5, Label: 14
  Edge list: 
    [0,1]   ID: N/A,  Label: 15
    [1,3]   ID: N/A,  Label: 20
    [2,5]   ID: N/A,  Label: 19

Graph 3 contains 2 vertices, and 1 edges
  Vertex list: 
    [0]   ID: 0, Label: 6
    [1]   ID: 1, Label: 11
  Edge list: 
    [0,1]   ID: N/A,  Label: 13

Graph 4 contains 4 vertices, and 3 edges
  Vertex list: 
    [0]   ID: 0, Label: 2
    [1]   ID: 1, Label: 11
    [2]   ID: 2, Label: 19
    [3]   ID: 3, Label: 2
  Edge list: 
    [0,1]   ID: N/A,  Label: 15
    [0,3]   ID: N/A,  Label: 19
    [1,2]   ID: N/A,  Label: 11

Graph 5 contains 3 vertices, and 4 edges
  Vertex list: 
    [0]   ID: 0, Label: 1
    [1]   ID: 1, Label: 16
    [2]   ID: 2, Label: 14
  Edge list: 
    [0,1]   ID: N/A,  Label: 8
    [0,2]   ID: N/A,  Label: 19
    [0,2]   ID: N/A,  Label: 19
    [1,2]   ID: N/A,  Label: 5
```

Comment: The code have been edited. How to make the additional inner loop please! I tried this loop as well but it doesn't work 

`std::cout << "dataG contains:";
        for( auto gr : dataG ) std::cout << gr->id << ' ' ;`

Comment: I haven't used the boost graph library, but after a quick look at the documentation, you might be able to iterate through the vertices with just `for (size_t i = 0 ; i < num_vertices(gr) ; ++i) { std::cout << gr[i].id << std::end;}` I've added this to the answer for clarity.

Comment: I should note that you probably won't get much on the output, as I don't see how the nodes can be properly populated from the code you provided.

Comment: Actually I want to put graphs in dataG and make sure by writing there id, so why to use num_vertices ?

Comment: Now I'm confused about what you really want to do. I assume you want to read the 5.txt data into a adjacency_list, as described by the properties you've defined. If that is the case. See my second edit.

Comment: Yes, I want to read graphs and there properties from txt file, creating and puting them in dataG and make sure by writing there id.

Comment: Ignore the part about `num_vertices`, since that was just a suggestion as to how to iterate the vertices to write the output of your `gr` graph objects. If what you want to do is populate the graphs, I've shown how to do so in the second edit.

Comment: Thanks a lot :) I think its ok for graph creation. 
How to make sure now by iterating over dataG I tried this but it doesn't work 
`std::cout << "dataG contains:";
        for( auto gr : dataG ) 
        {
            
            
              std::cout << ' ' << gr.id << std::endl;
            
        }`

Comment: I've added another update to show how you can access and output the data from the graphs. I almost feel fooled into doing all the work for you ;) Nevertheless, I've now learned some of `boost`'s graph library, which can be useful at some point. Bon courage.

Comment: If you feel the answer is acceptable, you can always choose to accept it ;)

Comment: Can you explain more about "stringstream" and ">>" please !

Comment: `stringstream` and `>>` usage is fairly basic c++, and you will find plenty of sources explaining it through a search on the web. If you have particular question regarding it, and  you can't find it asked on stackoverflow, ask it.

Comment: I suggest reading a book on c++. It will save you a lot of time if you invest in doing it properly, early.

Comment: And it will save the community a lot of time @swalog :) +1 for effort, but really, we should try to be less of a personal helpdesk here. Teach a man how to fish etc.